# How to chain file objects in Python?

Tags: python, csv, functional-programming

I'm trying to find a simple way to chain file-like objects. I have a single CSV file which is split into a number of segments on disk. I'd like to be able to pass them to `csv.DictReader` without having to make a concatenated temporary first.

Something like:

```py
files = map(io.open, filenames)
for row in csv.DictReader(io.chain(files)):
    print(row[column_name])
```

But I haven't been able to find anything like `io.chain`. If I were parsing it myself, I could do something like:

```py
from itertools import chain

def lines(fp):
    for line in fp.readlines():
        yield line

a = open('segment-1.dat')
b = open('segment-2.dat')
for line in chain(lines(a), lines(b)):
    row = line.strip().split(',')
```

However `DictReader` needs something it can call `read()` on, so this method doesn't work. I can iterate over the files, copying the `fieldnames` property from the previous reader, but I was hoping for something which let me put all the processing within a single loop body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iterable might help

```py
from io import BytesIO


a = BytesIO(b"1st file 1st line \n1st file 2nd line")
b = BytesIO(b"2nd file 1st line \n2nd file 2nd line")

class Reader: 
    def __init__(self, *files): 
        self.files = files 
        self.current_idx = 0

    def __iter__(self): 
        return self 

    def __next__(self): 
        f = self.files[self.current_idx]
        for line in f: 
            return line 
        else: 
            if self.current_idx < len(self.files) - 1:
                self.current_idx += 1
                return next (self)
        raise StopIteration("feed me more files") 

r = Reader(a, b)

for l in r:
    print(l)
```

Result:

```py
b'1st file 1st line \n'
b'1st file 2nd line'
b'2nd file 1st line \n'
b'2nd file 2nd line'
```

**Edit:**

:D then there are standard library goodies.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html

```py
with fileinput.input(files=('spam.txt', 'eggs.txt')) as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

Comment: Yes, `fileinput` is the cleanest thing here, now that martineau explained I can use it with `DictReader`. I'll go with that.

Comment: @Ralph: A potential problem of using `fileinput` is that it doesn't open the files with `newline=''` as the `csv` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) recommends.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class that's an iterator that returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called (quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)).

```
import csv


class ChainedCSVfiles:
    def __init__(self, filenames):
        self.filenames = filenames

    def __iter__(self):
        return next(self)

    def __next__(self):
        for filename in self.filenames:
            with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
                for line in csvfile:
                    yield line


filenames = 'segment-1.dat', 'segment-2.dat'
reader = csv.DictReader(ChainedCSVfiles(filenames),
                        fieldnames=('field1', 'field2', 'field3'))
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Oh! So `DictReader` *can* take a iterable, it just has to be of lines. Thanks, I'd missed that in the docs and misunderstood the problem I was having.